# Добавить переменную в ajax-запрос

Tags: jquery

Есть некоторая функция, передает форму, рабочая

```
function SendPost(forma, obj) {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/save.php', //Адрес подгружаемой страницы
    type: 'POST', //Тип запроса
    dataType: 'html', //Тип данных
    data: jQuery("#"+forma).serialize(),
    success: function(response) { //Если все нормально
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = response;
    },
    error: function(response) { //Если ошибка
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Ошибка при отправке формы";
    }
});
```

}

Переменной *obj* я пытаюсь передать id кнопки, как добавить эту переменную в *data*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот например вариант:

```
var values = jQuery("#"+forma).serializeArray();
values.push({
  name: "id",
  value: obj
});
values = jQuery.param(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте отдельную переменную для хранения необходимых данных для передачи.

```
dataToSend = jQuery("#"+forma).serialize();
```

В таком случае, если вам понадобится добавить новые данные, достаточно будет использовать `.push` метод:

```
dataToSend.Push({"name":"имя","value":"значение" });
```